# Change the column of the dataframe Pandas to value of one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a data table that is look like this

```
                              Value      
Code                          ABCD GFHTI
Time                                    
20100101_00:01:33.436-92.451    24  None
20100101_00:01:33.638-92.651  None    25
```

The table is obtained from the log file

```
logparser = parse_filter_logfile('log.txt')
df = pd.DataFrame(logparser, columns = ['Time', 'Code', 'Value'])
df.set_index(['Time', 'Code']).unstack(-1)
```

I used `df.pivot(index='Time', columns=['ABCD','GFHTI'])` to change the column to ABCD and GFHTI but I got the following error KeyError: 'Level ABCD not found'.

```
Time                           ABCD GFHTI           
20100101_00:01:33.436-92.451    24  None
20100101_00:01:33.638-92.651  None    25
```

What I want to have a table with the columns name of and look like something this:

Is there any work around this ?

Here is the full code, 
log.txt

```
20100101_00:01:33.436-92.451 BLACKBOX ABCD ref 2183 value 24 
20100101_00:01:33.638-92.651 BLACKBOX GFHTI  ref 2183 value 25 
20100101_00:01:33.817-92.851 BLACKBOX AAAA ref 2183 value 26   
20100101_00:01:34.017-93.051 BLACKBOX BBBB ref 2183 value 27
```

> and this the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def parse_line(line):
    code_pattern = r'(?<=BLACKBOX )\w+'
    value_pattern = r'(?<=value )\d+'
    code = re.findall(code_pattern, line)[0]
    value = re.findall(value_pattern, line)[0]
    ts = line.split()[0]
    print (type(value))
    return ts, code, value

def parse_filter_logfile(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
       for line in f:
           data = parse_line(line)
           if data[1] in ['ABCD', 'GFHTI']:
               # only yield rows that match the filter
                print((data))
                yield data

logparser = parse_filter_logfile('log.txt')
df = pd.DataFrame(logparser, columns = ['Time', 'Code', 'Value'])

df.set_index(['Time', 'Code']).unstack(-1)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have a `MultiIndex` of columns, so just dropping the level, using `droplevel`, should be fine.

```
df = df.set_index(['Time', 'Code']).unstack(-1)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

```
df

Code                          ABCD GFHTI
Time                                    
20100101_00:01:33.436-92.451    24  None
20100101_00:01:33.638-92.651  None    25
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. that didn't work I got the `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'droplevel'`

Comment: @Behinoo My understanding is that your current pivot result is the first dataframe posted, and your expected output is the second. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You are right the first dataframe is what I have and I want the output to be the second one. I added the simplified script that recreate  the issue related to the question.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into it.

Comment: @Behinoo I tried the code with your setup, and it worked perfectly for me. What is the output of the `df.columns` after the set_index+unstack operation?

Comment: you are right. I changed the code to following and solved the issue, I think the problem was inplace='true' issue probably.   `H=df.set_index(['Time', 'Code']).unstack(-1)
H.columns = H.columns.droplevel(0)`

Comment: with this dataframe how I can set the Time as my only index and keep the smae structure ?

Comment: @COLDSPEED that is correct, currently my index are both  (['Time', 'Code']) but I want to see if I can only have Time as my index and still have the same shape for my dataframe.

Comment: @COLDSPEED so for example now I don't have Time as one of the column and when  I put    H['Time'], I get error .

Comment: @Behinoo Should the index just have `00:01:33.436`?

Comment: @COLDSPEED very good point, the index should be 20100101_00:01:33 which is  "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"  that was another issue when I am dealing with my real text file and modify `return ts, code, value`  to `return ts[0:17] , code, value' I get  `Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`. this probably due some space or something in original data

Comment: @Behinoo Alright. I have to go afk for a few hours, so you could either hold on a bit, or ask a new question. Sorry about that. If your question isn't resolved by the time I'm back (a few hours), I'll handle it.